# Unknown class _TtC7xxx in interface builder file

Tags: swift, xcode8

Hello I am using xcode 8 and swift 3. I have a custom UICollectionViewController called HomeCollectionViewController that I set to my UICollectionViewController in my storyboard. The app has no errors and compiles and runs, but in the console I get the message Unknown class _TtC7Reacshn28HomeCollectionViewController in interface builder file. This must be from the compiler as I do not have such a class or file.

In the Identity Inspector I set the class to HomeCollectionViewController and the Module has defaulted to my app, Reacshn. Inherit from Target was also auto checked when I set the class, but unchecking that does not help.

[image]

Comment: `_TtC7Reachshn28HomeCollectionViewController` is the mangled name of your controller class. What strange is module portion is `7Reachshn` but `Reachshn` is actually 8 characters long. It also differs from what you said in the question: `Reachshn` vs. `Reacshn`

Comment: In [this image](http://imgur.com/D8OIRUi), the module `mac` doesn't exist. The app crashed with an error: `Unknown class _TtC3mac14ViewController in Interface Builder file`. Make sure you spell it correctly or leave it blank (if your class name is unambiguous)

Comment: Sorry I fixed the spelling